# How to fix NavigationDuplicated error in Internet Explorer?

Tags: vue.js, internet-explorer, navigation, vue-router

I am developing a "Vue" application that consists of a form to make a purchase.
In all the browsers it makes me the complete cycle without any problem, managing to make the "post" at the end of the form.
On the other hand, when I try to do the flow in Internet Explorer, after filling in the last step of the form, it redirects to the next page but does not load the component, returning the error "Uncaught (in promise) NavigationDuplicated: Avoided redundant navigation to current location: "/devis/resume".
this is my router

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Devis from '../components/devis/devis.vue'
import Animal from '../components/devis/animal.vue'
import Create from '../components/devis/create.vue'
import Resume from '../components/devis/resume.vue'
import Service from '../components/devis/service.vue'
import Geo from '../components/extern/geolocalisation.vue'
import Message from '../components/extern/servicenotavailable.vue'



Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: Devis, children: [
        {
          path: '/',
          component: Animal
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      path: '/devis',
      component: Devis, children: [
        {
          path: '/',
          component: Animal
        },
        {
          path: 'create',
          component: Create
        },
        {
          path: 'resume',
          component: Resume
        },
        {
          path: 'service',
          component: Service
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      path: '/geo',
      component: Geo
    },
    {
      path: '/message',
      component: Message
    }
  ],
  mode: 'history', 
  scrollBehavior() {
    document.getElementById('app').scrollIntoView();
  }

})
```

and here is the point at which I redirect from create component to the resume component

```
    checkForm() {
      
      if (
        this.ownerFormInfo.civility !== "" &&
        this.ownerFormInfo.firstName !== "" &&
        this.ownerFormInfo.lastName !== "" &&
        this.ownerFormInfo.adresse1 !== "" &&
        this.ownerFormInfo.city !== "" &&
        (this.ownerFormInfo.postalCode === "" ||
          (this.ownerFormInfo.postalCode !== "" &&
            this.validatePostalCode(this.ownerFormInfo.postalCode))) &&
        (this.ownerFormInfo.phone === "" ||
          (this.ownerFormInfo.phone !== "" &&
            this.validatePhone(this.ownerFormInfo.phone))) &&
        (this.ownerFormInfo.email === "" ||
          (this.ownerFormInfo.email !== "" &&
            this.validateEmail(this.ownerFormInfo.email)))
      ) {
        this.onSubmit();
      }
    },
    onSubmit() {
      const formData = {
        civility: this.ownerFormInfo.civility,
        firstName: this.ownerFormInfo.firstName,
        lastName: this.ownerFormInfo.lastName,
        adresse1: this.ownerFormInfo.adresse1,
        adresse2: this.ownerFormInfo.adresse2,
        adresse3: this.ownerFormInfo.adresse3,
        city: this.ownerFormInfo.city,
        postalCode: this.ownerFormInfo.postalCode,
        phone: this.ownerFormInfo.phone.indexOf('0') == 0 ? this.ownerFormInfo.phone.replace('0', '+33') : this.ownerFormInfo.phone,
        email: this.ownerFormInfo.email
      };

      const owner = {
        ownerCivility: formData.civility,
        ownerLastname: formData.lastName,
        ownerFirstname: formData.firstName,
        ownerAddressFirstLine: formData.adresse1,
        ownerAddressSecondLine: formData.adresse2,
        ownerAddressThirdLine: formData.adresse3,
        ownerPostalCode: formData.postalCode,
        ownerCity: formData.city,
        ownerPhone: formData.phone,
        ownerEmail: formData.email,
        country: "FR"
      };

      this.$store.dispatch("formOwnerStepInfo", formData);
      const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

      let config = {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + token
        }
      };

      globalAxios
        .post("/api/fr/estimations", owner, config)
        .then(res => {
          if (res.data.functional_id) {
            this.$store.dispatch("setFunctionalId", res.data.functional_id);
          }
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));

      this.navigateToResume();
    },
    navigateToResume() {
      this.$store.dispatch("setStep", this.step + 1);
      this.$router.push("/devis/resume");
    },
```

How can it be that in the rest of the browsers it works correctly?

What am I doing wrong?

I've been looking for information but I can't find a way to fix the error or reference it as being due to Internet Explorer.

Greetings and thank you all for your time and help in advance

Comment: Which version of vue-router are you using? I find some threads with similar issue and they say the issue is caused by vue-router version. You can try to use vue-router below version 3.0 to see if it can work. Besides, please provide [a reproducible code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or sample link in online editor so that we can have a test and see how to help.

Comment: hi  @YuZhou the version of vue-router is "vue-router": "^3.0.1", I will try to download the version to see if it works thank you

Comment: @YuZhou i have downloaded the router version to 2.8.1and the error is no longer displayed on the console but the component is still not loaded.

Comment: Please provide a minimal code sample which can reproduce the issue. Your code above is not complete to reproduce. You can provide your sample using some online code editors like stackblitz, codesandbox or others.

Comment: @YuZhou Thanks a lot for answering, I found a reference to what you told me before about incompatibility of versions and going down to 2.6.0 of the router the failure has disappeared!

Comment: That's great! You can also put this solution as an answer and mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found several threads, thanks to the help of Yu Zhou in comments, referring to similar problems caused by the vue-router version. All of them suggest using the vue-router below version 3.0.
In my case I first lowered it to 2.8 and there was no difference , but then I lowered it to 2.6 and the problem was solved.